# Converting a VBScript to Python

Tags: python, vbscript, binary, odbc, pyodbc

I have the following vbscript running on a Windows machine:

```vb
db = "\\networklocation\Database\employeeID.mdb"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set mstream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
'ADODB.Stream is need to transfer the BLOB Data as Binary

mstream.Type = 1 '' 1 is to: adTypeBinary 
'for info on Stream: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_stream.asp

cn.Open "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & "Data Source =" & db

strSQL = "SELECT IDNumber,photo FROM employeeID WHERE IDNumber like 'A00______' and photo is not null" 
'% for 0 or more characters, _ to replace a single character

rs.Open strSQL, cn
DO WHILE not rs.eof
mstream.Open
mstream.Write rs("photo")
mstream.SaveToFile "C:\images\all\" & rs("IDNumber") & ".jpg", 2 'adSaveCreateOveWrite
mstream.close
rs.movenext
Loop
```

It does exactly what I need it to do, but after getting the pictures, I need to send them to a Linux machine, which I use winscp to send.

I would like to run the script from the Linux server, taking the need for winscp and the windows machine (I don't like running stuff from multiple locations) out of the equation.

I recently discovered that Python can connect to an Access database using pyodbc.

I believe I understand how to connect to the access database, but not sure about how to extract binary data out of one column and label them with a different column in Python. (Extracting the binary data was the biggest hurdle I had when creating the VBScript)

UPDATE:
Looks like I can close this idea for now, I didn't realize that all the ODBC Drivers on Linux cost money. searching for other methods now, like jackness which is a direct java connection to the access

Comment: SO is not a free translation service. What you're asking is basically for people her to rewrite of your script from scratch, since VBScript and Python are not much alike. That's not very likely to happen.

Comment: This page should get you started with most of what you need to know to get it converted: https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted What Ansgar said is correct, however; in addition, you should be sure to know what code you're running before you run it.

Comment: I'm not looking for you to write the script, just looking for what might help find the pieces that I need for the python code. like the link FlipperPA added. and the code micebrain added. When I get a rough outline of the code, I'm planning to post it with more questions if I can get around certain issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the column data into a file in binary mode.

E.g. Assuming the image is in first column...

---

```
data = cursor.execute(selectstmt).fetchone()
with open('img.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data[0])
```

---

Comment: In the second argument to file open - wb = write binary